# XPages - Process to update production with minimal down time

Tags: xpages

Is there a best practice process to update an xpages application in production?
At the moment (after testing against a development server) I will..

- Refresh a local replica of the production db with the dev template
- Build the local replica
- Replicate back to production

If I follow that process the production system will go down for about 20 minutes after replication responding with a "HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception error." It will come back by itself eventually, reflecting the new change.

So the question(s) are:

1. Is there a 'better' way to update production which would minimise downtime
2. If not, any ideas what the server could be doing for those 20 mins? there are no application scope beans to re-initialise, only sessionScope ones.  In the logs there are lots of these errors...

   5/13/14 3:55 PM: Exception Thrown
   java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:88)
   at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
   at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
   at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
   at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
   at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
   at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
   at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
   at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
   at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
   at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
   at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
   at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)

Answer (score 1):

Here are my thoughts.
I would NEVER have any replication going on between dev and production. That's just way too risky in my opinion and not a Best Practice. Maybe that's not exactly what you're doing I'm not sure.

Here's what I do and as far as I know everyone on my team:

Our Dev server has a test database.  This is a COPY from production.  Personally I refresh it now and then so it's basically a snapshot.

We have a local template for all dev work.  We program in the template and refresh the test database.  Typically we don't need to do a "restart task http" as part of the refresh process UNLESS we make a change to a managed bean or are working with SXD.  Then yes we refresh the dev application and restart the server and test.

In the OLD days I would have a production template on the production server.  This was not a replica of anything but it inherited design from the DEV template.  So to promote updates to production I'd first refresh the production template from the dev version.  Then refresh the production app from the production template.

In the world of source control and SourceTree where you have a feature branch, develop branch and default/production branch that kinda eliminates the need for a production template. I'm not in love with that but it is what it is.  So we refresh production from our local templates and rely on SourceTree to make sure it's the correct branch at the time we refresh.  I think it's a little more risky but this allows the ability to do real hotfixes and stuff.

Historically I've not needed to do a restart task http but I've not promoted anything that uses SXD and even my managed bean promotions have been limited to this point. But I imagine I will need to do more with restarting the http task.

Comment: We used to keep production templates where the template name property and the file name reflected the version. Instead of refresh design we use replace design. So you can roll back if required quickly

Comment: Thanks David. Just to be clear nothing is replicating between prod and dev. Dev is a separate copy and I am using(learnign!) SourceTree/GitHub to manage the changes.
The issue is more with how to get the changes into production when you want to do a release. Rather than updating the design on the prod server directly (via replace or refresh) I was doing that via a local replica of the prod nsf. Sounds like that shoudn't be needed though unless there's bad comms

Comment: Stephan - In theory if you're using SourceControl properly rolling back should be as simple as changing to a previous branch and then refreshing design.

Comment: Martin - yeah.  We just refresh the design directly.  Replace would work as well - I'm not sure of pros/cons for either.  Personally I think either is better then using replication to push the changes out.

Answer (score 1):

In my normal use, I go the replace-design route on the production server. This still involves a bit of down time that scales with the size of the design and speed of connection to the server, but it's not too bad. That could be shortened if you did the design replace with a client running on the server itself.

I haven't done this, but my guess is that the absolute least down time would be to have the production DB follow a named NTF on the server. Do a replace design on that NTF and then run "load design -f proddb.nsf" on the server - I'd think that that would be the fastest way to bring the design elements in.

As for the "wait half an hour" problem, I'm not sure what the cause of that would be. I saw something similar on a client's server running 8.5.2 this week, but the delay was more on the order of a minute. I haven't seen anything of the like on my servers. One out-of-the-blue guess: maybe it's related to the "refresh application on design change" property added to xsp.properties in 8.5.3 (and which I've used since). That could explain the "fixes itself in half an hour" thing: the app could unload itself automatically in that period, whereas turning that option on would cause it to do so immediately.

Comment: I second the `load design` on the server approach. Normally when I have a new release of an application ready, I create a copy from the DEV version that will be the (new) template that the production database inherits from (with a new version number). Once I have this template on the production server I build and sign it, update the template name that the production database inherits from and call the `load design` to update it. Updating a design on the server this way normally shouldn't take more than a minute.

Comment: Thanks Jesse and Mark.  I'll try the next release via an ntf on prod and a load design command and see how that goes.  I'll also try the xsp:property change
NB: There's a logfilereader db (one of the common ones) on the server and that's completely unresponsive during this 30 min downtime. It's as if the JVM memory has gone crazy, consumed entirely by doing something or other.  Perhaps I need to figure out if the app is taking a long time to unload after the design update (freeing up memory?) or a long time reloading

Comment: It's also worth bearing in mind that although you may not have any applicationScope beans, the application will also need to store other information in applicationScope. Looking at one of my apps with Mark Leusink's debug toolbar, it has things like javax.servlet.context.tempdir, com.sun.faces.ApplicationAssociate, com.sun.faces.OneTimeInitialization. It also has a viewStateBean (presumably because I'm using the Pager Save State control). "Refresh application on design change" may actually solve the problem of needing a 30 minute wait, by reloading the app immediately.

Comment: I have yet to find a reason NOT to set that xsp.properties option, honestly. I can't think of a situation when you would want its behavior - theoretically, having it off would allow you to retain app/session/view-scoped data when you change the design, but the reality is that it always leads to trouble for even moderately-sized apps. In my worst case, I had an app break with ClassCastExceptions when I changed the ACL until 8.5.3 and this option came out.